# Linq.ConvertAll to convert class to there interface type

Tags: c#

I have a class App which implements IApp interface class 
this IApp interface is like this

```
    interface IApp
    {
        string Status;
        dateTime start;
        datetime end;
    }
```

now i want to convert List to List by using Linq
this I can do like this

```
//AppClassList is a List<App>
List<IApp> result = AppClassList.ConvertAll<IApp>(o => (IApp)o);
```

but I want to do custom code while converting App to IApp,
like I want to set Status property depend on start and end date diffrence , suppose difference is one day then Status will be "Excellent"  if two day then "Good" if three day then "OK" and so on ...

Please suggest me how i can do it while converting App to IApp using C#.net

Comment: You don't inherit an interface, you implement it.

Comment: yes this line is compiling List<IApp> result = AppClassList.ConvertAll<IApp>(o => (IApp)o);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<IApp> result = AppClassList.ConvertAll<IApp>(o => ConvertToIApp(o));
    {
        IApp result = (IApp)o;
        TimeSpan span = result .end - result .start;
        if (span.TotalDays > 1)
        {
           result.Status = "Excellent";
        }
        return result;
    });
```

and having this method:

```
public IApp ConvertToIApp(Object element)
{
    IApp result = (IApp)element;
    TimeSpan span = result.end - result.start;
    if (span.TotalDays > 1)
    {
        result.Status = "Excellent";
    }
    return result;
}
```

you could write:

```
List<IApp> result = AppClassList.ConvertAll<IApp>(o => ConvertToIApp(o));
```

or

```
List<IApp> result = AppClassList.ConvertAll<IApp>(ConvertToIAppo);
```

Comment: Can we call any method inside convertall which calculate value and return same

Comment: Yes, we can use any code there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: This uses a lambda to achieve the same as my answer +1

Answer (score 0):

think you're after:

```
someList.Cast<OtherType>();
```

you might want to stick ToList() on there aswell + could always wrap that up in your own extension method.

Answer (score 0):

ok,

```
IList<SomeIAppImplementor> before = ...
var iapps = new List<IApp>(before.Count)

for (i = 0; i < before.Count; i++)
{
    var iapp = (IApp)before[i];
    if (iapp. ...
    {
         iapp.Status = ...
    }
    iapps[i] = iapp;
}
```

---

This will iterate the list exactly once while using the indexer which, I think is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use select and then in the lambda `=>` open parentheses `{}` and then handle what you want to do in there - you say you want to set the status based on the difference.

```
  List<App> appList = new List<App>();
  List<IApp> iAppList = appList.Select(x =>
  {
    IApp app = x;
    int difference = (app.end - app.start).Days;
    if (difference == 1)
      app.Status = "Good";
    return app;
  }).ToList();
```

Also make your interface have properties which can be set within the `App` class, this will then cast to IApp and set IApp's properties appropriately.

```
  interface IApp
  {
    string Status {get; set;}
    DateTime start {get; set;}
    DateTime end {get; set;}
  }
```

Comment: Using `Select` will use the `Enumerator` where as `ConvertAll` would access the `indexer` which would be advantageous for a `List<T>`